# SAP HANA SQL FLOAT TO DATE

Tags: sql, date, casting, floating-point, hana

In SAP, some dates are stored in tables as **floats**, as shown below for column `ATFLV` of table `AUSP`, which has the value `2.0181218000000000E+07`:

```
txt
MANDT OBJEK                     ATINN ATZHL MAFID KLART ADZHL ATWRT ATFLV

100   000000000000004148   9999999400   001 O     023    0000       2.0181218000000000E+07
```

Other example:
[image]

I know these are supposed to be dates, but I can't find any function to transform. I have considered using Add_seconds (assuming the values stored are in milliseconds), but I don't know what base date to use `1/1/1900` or `1/1/1970`?

I appreciate the help.

29.11.2021 EDIT

Just to add some context, I am using HANA DB studio to create a calculation view that does this transformation, using a Table function in HANA SQL.

Comment: Please paste the text instead of image, so that people can simply again copy and paste in their answers. I did it for you.

Comment: `2.0181218000000000E+07` means `20181218` (E+07 is to shift the decimal separator to the right by 7 positions). No need to transform, the format is YYYYMMDD i.e. December 18th, 2018.

Comment: I'm not an SAP person but a quick Google brought up multiple references to CTCV_CONVERT_FLOAT_TO_DATE

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to support your question.

Comment: @NickW You assume it's an ABAP question, but it seems to be a HANA SQL question.

Comment: I think the question is how does SAP store dates as floats - as that is a pre-requisite of being able to write SQL that will reverse-engineer the float back to a date. If the internal code for the CTCV_CONVERT_FLOAT_TO_DATE function is available then it will provide the required information

Comment: No need to reverse-engineer, my second comment already describes the logic, which corresponds to this ABAP code: `DATA(date) = CONV d( CONV num8( numeric_value ) ).` Of course the required double conversion would deserve a little explanation.

Comment: Thank you @SandraRossi... I feel a little bit embarrassed that I had not notice that before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments and help from @SandraRossi I have been able to solve my problem using the following:

```
TO_DATE(LEFT(REPLACE("VALUE_OLD", '.',''),8))
```